# Correctly scale DOT graphic

Tags: d3.js, graphviz

Please,

I need to create an SVG graphic with D3-GraphViz that size fits perfectly to a DIV area. I tried many this but without success.

Here is a sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@1.4.0/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .fade(false)
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');

</script>
```

I saw on D3 website that is a ".fit(true)" property but it simply doesn't work. Any ideas or examples?

Comment: I believe you're mistaken, there is no `fit()` method in D3 (because D3 doesn't create any graphic, it's just a collection of functions). Can you share this website?

Comment: Hi @Geraldo Furtado it's here: https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz#graphviz_fit

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That's not D3, that's just a plugin which uses D3. Here is a list of D3 plugins, where you'll find Graphviz: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Plugins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with CSS, scaling the `svg` that Graphviz produces up to the size of your master element `#graph`:

```
#graph svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  #graph {
    /* Just an example */
    height: 250px;
  }
  #graph svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/viz.js@1.8.0/viz.js" type="javascript/worker"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@1.4.0/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
<script>

d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .fade(false)
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Just realised the source js was so out-of-date (I copied that line from an example as well). Simply change the reference to

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@2.6.1/build/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
```

After that all functionalities listed in README.md of the github repo became available.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the [fit()](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz#graphviz_fit) method:

> Note that unless the SVG size has been changed, this options has no effect.

Here's an example showing how to fit the SVG perfectly to a DIV area:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@hpcc-js/wasm@0.3.13/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-graphviz@3.1.0/build/d3-graphviz.js"></script>
<div id="graph-container" style="width: 50%; height: 500px; margin:auto; border: 1px solid black"></div>
<script>

const graphContainer = d3.select("#graph-container");
const width = graphContainer.node().clientWidth;
const height = graphContainer.node().clientHeight;

graphContainer.graphviz()
    .width(width)
    .height(height)
    .fit(true)
    .renderDot('digraph  {a -> b}');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about d3, but in pure Graphviz there are tools to control the output size, especially graph attribute [size](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:size) in pair with [ratio](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:ratio). They are described in details over the links but let me show just one example:

**without `size` or `ratio`:**

```
digraph {
    c ->d
    a -> b
}
```

[image]

**with `size` and `ratio=compress`:**

```
digraph {
    size="10,5"
    ratio=compress
    c ->d
    a -> b
}
```

[image]

If it's js, you can supply the `size` arguments dynamically, right?

Comment: I comprehend what you have said @Dany. But the problem is that when I do this the graphic looks small inside the DIV - that continues with the same size ;)